How to add multiple scrape URLs to prometheus.yml?
I want to use Grafana/Prometheus to collect metrics from components. Grafana, Prometheus, node_exporter, Wildfly are running fine.
I want to collect metrics from:

http://localhost:9090/metrics (Prometheus itself)
http://localhost:9182/metrics (node exporter)
http://localhost:9990/metrics (Wildfly)
http://localhost:8080/application/rest/metrics (my application inside Wildfly)

How to configure it in prometheus.yml? I tried the following, but this does not work:
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9100", "localhost:9990", "localhost:9090"]
        labels:
            group: 'system'
  - job_name: "application"
    metrics_path: "/application/rest/metrics"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8080"]
        labels:
            group: 'application'


Please try this configuration:
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: node_exporter
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9182']
  - job_name: wildfly
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9990']
  - job_name: application
    metrics_path: '/application/rest/metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']


I tried this. When I call http://localhost:9090/targets I see only one target called prometheus with endpoint of prometheus server itself.

I found my fault. I adjusted @mefeka solution to a working configuration. Current version of Prometheus allows only hostnames in targets parameter.
